# Jquery using ajax post to manipulate html template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i'm doing this

1. Php page citySearchResultListElement.php

   ```
   <?php 
   $cityId =  $_GET['city_Id'];
   $cityName =  $_GET['city_screen_name'];
   ?>
   <li class="result">
   <a target="_blank" href="javascript:selectedCityInSearch('<?php echo $cityId; ?>','<?php echo $cityName; ?>');">
   <h2><?php echo $cityName; ?></h2></a>
   </li>
   ```
2. A javascript that does this ajax call

   ```
   function getMockupElementHtml(resourceObject,
   var url = 'pageMockups/' + resourceObject + '.php';
   var content = '';
   content = $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'GET', 
           data: paramArray,
           dataType: 'text',
           crossDomain: true
       }).done(function (data) {
                               content = data;
                                   })
   .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       console.log(xhr.responseText);
                       console.log(textStatus);
                       console.log(errorThrown);

                       }
         );
   return content;
   }
   ```
3. And i call it from

   ```
   function test(resourceObject,paramArray)
   {
   var myObject = getMockupElementHtml(resourceObject,paramArray);
   console.log(myObject);
   return myObject;
   }
   ```

Using debugging tools, i can see that myObject isn't what i'm expecting. I'm expecting plain html code that i will use further in another function, but i'm getting this

```
Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function (e){return e=e||S,o&&o.abort(e),T(0,e),this}
always: function (){return i.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}
complete: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
done: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
error: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
fail: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return E===2?i:null}
getResponseHeader: function (e){var n;if(E===2){if(!s){s={};while(n=pn.exec(i))s[n[1].toLowerCase()]=n[2]}n=s[e.toLowerCase()]}return n===t?null:n}
overrideMimeType: function (e){return E||(c.mimeType=e),this}
pipe: function (){var e=arguments;return v.Deferred(function(n){v.each(t,function(t,r){var s=r[0],o=e[t];i[r[1]](v.isFunction(o)?function(){var e=o.apply(this,arguments);e&&v.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[s+"With"](this===i?n:this,[e])}:n[s])}),e=null}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
promise: function (e){return e!=null?v.extend(e,r):r}
readyState: 4
responseText: "<li class="result"><a target="_blank"  href="javascript:selectedCityInSearch('1925','Sarakhs (Iran, Islamic Republic Of)');">
<h2>Sarakhs (Iran, Islamic Republic Of)</h2></a>
</li>"
setRequestHeader: function (e,t){if(!E){var n=e.toLowerCase();e=w[n]=w[n]||e,b[e]=t}return this}
state: function (){return n}
status: 200
statusCode: function (e){if(e){var t;if(E<2)for(t in e)g[t]=[g[t],e[t]];else t=e[x.status],x.always(t)}return this}
statusText: "OK"
success: function (){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
then: function (){var e=arguments;return v.Deferred(function(n){v.each(t,function(t,r){var s=r[0],o=e[t];i[r[1]](v.isFunction(o)?function(){var e=o.apply(this,arguments);e&&v.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):n[s+"With"](this===i?n:this,[e])}:n[s])}),e=null}).promise()}
```

**proto**: Object

The value that i'm looking for is the one after responseText:

How can i access it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are wrapping asynchronous code in synchronous code, and using conflicting variable names.

```
var content = '';
content = $.ajax({ //content variable is now a jqXHR object returned from $.ajax()
        url: url,
        type: 'GET', 
        data: paramArray,
        dataType: 'text',
        crossDomain: true
}).done(function (data) {
    content = data; //this does happen until AFTER content is returned to calling function
})
.fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);

                    }
      );
return content;//content is still jqXHR at this point
```

In order to fix this, do not use returns, simple do what you want to do with the data inside the callback:

```
.done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

Comment: Can't i use a jQuery ajax call to return a value to a javascript function? My target is to use the getMockupElementHtml as a "template provider" and to handle what it returns in a separate javascript function...

Comment: @user3385666 yes, if you make your ajax call synchronous, but then you will lock up the browser until the call completes, which could be a while. Asynchronicity is one of javascripts strong points, dont try and fight it.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. It doesn't matter if call is async, because it's a very simple call but it has to be dynamic and invoked through javascript. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this could be the issue:

```
function getMockupElementHtml(resourceObject,
```

above you have not closed the "()" parenthesis, also seems that you have missed some arguments as well.

---

This should be:

```
function getMockupElementHtml(resourceObject, paramArray){ // <---like this
```

---

Another thing is that you can remove these:

```
dataType: 'text',
crossDomain: true
```

and change to this:

```
dataType: 'html',
```

Comment: Im fairly sure this is a synchronicity problem

Comment: Yes, probably i mistyped something in the question where the code is, anyway the functions are correct in my code, there's no lacking parameter error.